# Spring security: show error 403 page instead of login form page for non-authenticated users

Tags: authentication, spring-security, http-status-code-403

I've set basic spring authentication. When user comes to page and enters secured URL, login form is rendered, but I want to show error 403 page (or any other page i choose).

If I understand correctly I can't use `access-denied-handler` because user is not authenticated at all.

**How do I show any other page than login form page to non-authenticated user, when he accesses secured URL?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `form-login` the default `AuthenticationEntryPoint` redirects to the login page.

You can override this by injecting a [custom entry point](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-entry-point-ref) using the `entry-point-ref` attribute.

You can use the code for `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` as a guideline (or use that directly if all you want is a response code sent to the client).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below tag in your security context file.

```
access-denied-page="<name of the page>"
```

add this in http tag like below:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/authenticationfailed.jsp">
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've set `access-denied-page="/error/403"`. URL is mapped to controller and is also set in web.xml as default URL for error code 403.