# Spring Security does not throw any exceptions

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

My spring security config:

```
<security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true" >
<security:intercept-url pattern="/game/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>

<security:form-login password-parameter="password"  username-parameter="username"  login-page="/"
            default-target-url="/game/" login-processing-url="/processLogin" authentication-failure-url="/"/>
<security:logout logout-url="/game/logout" logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true"/>
<security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</security:http>
```

Custom handler:

```
@Component
public class AccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
@Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exception)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.handle(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

Exception resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".AccessDeniedException">accessDenied</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem I have is that spring security does not throw any exceptions. For example, when I enter a protected url, it redirects me to the login page. If I delete login page from the config, it redirects me to spring security default login form. Because of that I can't handle any exceptions like AccessDeniedException. As you can see above, I have defined custom access denied handler which overrides handle method but it doesn't even go inside it. I also tried with SimpleMappingExceptionResolver but that does not work either.
So my question is: How do I make spring security throw exceptions so I can catch them by either resolver or custom handler?

Comment: `AccessDeniedHandler` only applies to authenticated users. Perhaps if you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve. Why don't you want Spring Security to authenticate users, for example?

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the info. Didn't know it applies only to authenticated user. What I'm trying to do is simply display my error page when unauthenticated user tries to access stuff for authenticated users only BUT without mapping it to any url so that users cannot manually enter /denied for example.

Comment: It's not clear from your question how users are actually authenticated or why you don't want them to be when they access the site. If you want to override the authentication process to deny access, you can use a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. The default on will redirect to the login page. Also don't use `auto-config`. It will create the login setup whether or not you configure it. Just remove it.

Comment: Removed auto-config, thanks for that. Now regarding my question, imagine that someone enters the home page (they are not authenticated yet) and manually tries to access stuff for authenticated users by typing the correct url. In this case spring just automatically redirects them to login page and what I want to do is simply display error page but again, without mapping it to url address.

Comment: So, as above, you want to override the default behaviour of displaying the login page. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9568401/241990) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why my AccessDeniedHandler didn't work is because it applies to authenticated users only, so in order to display an error page when unauthenticated user tries to access stuff for authenticated users only(that was the purpose of trying to catch an AccessDeniedException), you should write your **custom entry point**, and override the default one.

Thanks to **Luke Taylor** for clarifying this to me.